# A structure which looks almost like a semi-ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request

Today I have encountered an interesting structure, similar to that of a ring or a semi-ring.

It is a structure $(S, +, \cdot, 1)$, where $S$ is a set, $+, \cdot$ are binary operations, and $1\in S$.

$(S, \cdot, 1)$ is a commutative monoid, $(S, +)$ is a commutative semigroup, and $+$ is distributive with respect to $\cdot$, i. e. $a(b+c) = ab+ac$ for any $a, b, c\in S$.

Does this structure have any names in the literature?

Comment: Why are you especially interested in dropping the requirement that $(S,+)$ has a neutral element? As far as I can tell this is the only thing making the structure you describe differ from a [semiring/rig](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig).

Comment: @mrtaurho because $(S, +)$ didn't have a neutral element to begin with in what I am dealing with. Also, it's not exactly the only thing that makes it different from a semi-ring. Note that in a semi-ring there is a requirement that $0x = x0 =  0$.

Comment: That's exactly my question: why asking for this special case? Do you have a particular example in mind which sparked your interest in this structure. I think it's odd as I can't think of a "trivial" (as e.g. the trivial ring $\{0\}$) structure satisfying these axioms *without* invoking a $0$. The absorption axiom has to be forced as it can't be deduced in the usual way from the other axioms (we're missing the conceps of negatives). Also, of course, we don't require $0x=0=x0$ if there is no $0$ to begin with :)

Comment: @mrtaurho In fact, I do have an example. The structure of exponents of prime numbers in a prime decomposition when adding or multiplying two natural numbers has this structure.

Comment: I am puzzled by the last comment, I am probably missunderstanding what you mean: exponets of powers don't behave nicely when adding two natural numbers.

Comment: @N.S. what are you puzzled about? I was just providing a context in which such structure arises naturally.

Comment: Again, unless I am missunderstanding what you mean, the exponents of powers  when adding or multiplying two natural numbers do not have this structure. or do you mean the powers of primes when multiplying/exponentiating natural numbers?  Also, primes do appear at the power 0, don't they?

Comment: @N.S. If you write $p = (p_1, p_2, \cdots)$, and define $p^a = \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{a_i}$, you can see that if you define $p^a\cdot p^b = p^{a \otimes b}$, $p^a+p^b = p^{a\oplus b}$, then the set of vectors that are eventually zero has this structure, with addition $\oplus$ and multiplication $\otimes$ . This is what I meant

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  Anyhow, this structure is just $(\mathbb N_{+}, +, \cdot)$.

Comment: What I mean here by "just" $(\mathbb N_{+}, +, \cdot)$ is the following. Consider the object $(\mathbb N_{+}, +, \cdot)$. The Fundamental theorem of arithmetic gives a bijection between $\mathbb N_{+}$ and your set, lets call it $P$. You are defining the operations via carrying forward the operations on $\mathbb N_{+}$ via this bijection, i.e. you are defining the only "structure" on $P$ which makes $f$ an isomorphism of "structures".

Comment: @N.S. but it is a different structure, and I realize I constructed it from natural numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully, I am not saying anything stupid here.

Consider such a set $S$. Define $R= S \cup \{ 0_R \}$ with the operations extended by 
$$
0_R+x =x \\
0_R\cdot x= 0_R$$

Then $R$ becomes a commutative semi-ring without zero divisors (i.e. $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$).

Converesely, let $R$ be any commutative semi-ring without zero divisors. Then
$$S= R \backslash \{ 0 \}$$
satisfies your given conditions.

In other words, your structures are just commutative semi-rings without zero divisors, with the zero removed.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question, but I accept this answer because it gives a good enough description of the structure at hand.